# Windows 8 offline login

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Your machine is offline please try to sign in with the last password used on this PC](https://superuser.com/questions/489811/your-machine-is-offline-please-try-to-sign-in-with-the-last-password-used-on-thi)

I am away for the holidays and went to log in on Windows 8. Because I am offline and it cannot access Windows Live it is asking for the last password used. I do not have one as this was a clean install and I have tried every password I've ever used but to no avail. I am stuck I cannot get into Window. I'm sure when I get home and it picks up my network and autoconnects I'll be fine but I need my computer now. I am at inlaws and computer is only escape. Had to borrow one to enetr this request. Also how do you enter safemode from Windows 8? Thank you!

Comment: To enter Safe mode on Windows 8, hold `Shift` button when you click **Restart**. When Windows is nearly done through shutdown process, it will display the options.

Comment: Have you logged in to this computer with your Microsoft account before? If you use Microsoft account, the first login must be done when you're online. Having a local account is a great way to overcome login issues to Microsoft account when you're offline.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Microsoft login for Windows 8 and not a local account, its your Microsoft account info. Eg. username@live.com or username@hotmail.com etc and whatever password you used.

Comment: But that only works if you're onlne. Because I'm unable to get online it requests the last password used which doesnt exist.I do not have a local account.

Comment: I believe it caches your last used password for that account. Have you given it a try first? If not, have you tried not putting in a password at all?

Comment: Yes have tried both and it always goes back to the password screen. A few times it has gone to a welcome screen like it is loading but then goes back to the sign in screen. So far I'm really not impressed with Windows 8.

Comment: I'm not impressed either. I can't seem to get the Security updates to install without failing.