# How do I change my Windows 8 login?

Tags: windows-8

I can't login to my laptop unless I'm connected to the internet. My windows 8 used my hotmail account and password. Is there a way to change that? I would love to use my laptop when traveling!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 offline login](http://superuser.com/questions/509003/windows-8-offline-login), http://superuser.com/questions/489811/your-machine-is-offline-please-try-to-sign-in-with-the-last-password-used-on-thi

Comment: I use a Microsoft Account to login to Windows 8 and I have never had a problem logging in without an Internet connection. Can you explain what happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

1. Drag your mouse to the right hand of the screen so the menu pops up.
2. Click `Change PC Settings`.
3. Click `Users`.
4. Under the Users Menu select `Switch To a Local Account` on the right hand side.
5. This will prompt you to create a new local user.

[image]