# What can I do when Windows 8 tells me I can't sign in because it's off-line?

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Your machine is offline please try to sign in with the last password used on this PC](https://superuser.com/questions/489811/your-machine-is-offline-please-try-to-sign-in-with-the-last-password-used-on-thi)

My new laptop running Windows 8 turns on and goes to the log in screen. I enter my correct password and it the tells me my PC is off-line and to sign in with the last password used? I can't get to the desktop and can't reset.