# Windows 8 - Cannot sign in without an internet connection

Tags: windows, windows-8, passwords

I have Windows 8 on my other laptop, and I can't sign onto my computer. I use one password for everything. My caps lock is not on. And I don't have an ethernet cable to connect to my laptop. The message after attempting to log in says "Your PC is offline. Please sign in with the last password used on this PC."

I have no idea what to do. I need to get on it ASAP. Ideas?

Note: I hit that little eyeball thing to reveal the password to make sure the keyboard isn't the issue. The password is correct and the problem is still persistent.

Comment: Could it be because you have your User connected to your Windows Live Account? When you get an Internet connection and login create a new *local* user and try logging into that without an internet connection.

Comment: See this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/489811/your-machine-is-offline-please-try-to-sign-in-with-the-last-password-used-on-thi

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have any way to connect it. Is there really no way to get into my Live Account with no connection?

Comment: Have you ever logged in with your Microsoft Account to this computer? If yes, then use the password you used last time you logged in to this computer. If not, I mean if it's the first time you log in to this computer with your Microsoft Account, you have to be online because otherwise Windows cannot verify your password.

Comment: Ethernet port is broken. I changed my homes wifi password. What should I do next?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely issue is that you have changed your Windows Live password since you last logged onto the PC. The issue could be that you are trying to sign in with a password that the PC doesnt know about yet. Basically, this could be solved by signing in with your old Windows Live password.

Note: I did read your question and i know you use one password for everything, im just leaving this here so if other people find this question they can try this as a solution.